# Building a REST API using node & Express.js, my PUT method doesn't work for some reason. Can anyone help me please?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

My data model :

```
var UserDetail = new Schema({
      username: String,
      password: String
    }, {
      collection: 'userInfo'
    });
var UserDetails = mongoose.model('userInfo', UserDetail);
```

This is my post method in the routes file

```
//POST
router.post( '/api/users', function( req, res ) {
    var user = new UserDetails({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    console.log(req.body.username);
    user.save( function( err ) {
        if( !err ) {
            console.log( 'created' );
            return res.send( user );
        } else {
            console.log( err );
            return res.send('ERROR');
        }
    });
});
```

My get api works perfect. The josn looks like this :

```
{"username":"exmpleUsername","password":"examplePassword","_id":"54091d9df8f00fb42055b6f8","__v":0}
```

But when I try to POST using POSTMAN, it doesn't add the username and password. It just adds new _id like this:

```
{"_id":"540e394f37706f701020cf19","__v":0}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Your Schema Class whether username and password is private

```
var Schema = function(){

    var self = this;

    var username = ""; // mean private

    self._id = ""; // mean public

};
```

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by "_id "?